# java glSurfaceView vs Native-Activity when using openGL ES from jni

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, opengl-es-2.0

I have a Android Project where i use JNI to render on gpu (openGL ES 2).

Currently i do this by creating a `glSurfaceView` in Java, and than use the `onDrawFrame` to invoke my JNI code that will execute the GLES commands. While this is working, the render speed is not good.

I was wondering if i could get better performance if i stopped using the java glSurfaceView to handle the context creation, but instead try to use a Native-Activity and do everything in cpp.

I think this way i can not use any java code anymore, so i most certainly will get into other troubles because my app needs to talk to some java android apis.

I can imagine that under the hood the Native-Activity (which i think is still wrapped by some java code) uses the same `glSurfaceView`, so there would be nothing to gain.

I am thankful for any infos on this topic.

All my drawing on GPU is done using `glDrawArray`. Maybe thats just not the fastest way to go on openGL ES ?

Comment: If all your rendering code is native already, I don't think turning this into a native activity would make a significant difference. The one JNI call per frame you need to invoke the native rendering code is insignificant.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i can verify that the jni calls and any non-gles code are not the bottleneck, because i get decent framerates as long as i disable all calls to glDrawArray. By now i got the renderspeed up quite a bit by playing around with EGLConfig (especially disabling the aa gave of course a huge boost in performance)

Answer (score 2):

You need to profile if bottleneck is software or GPU. After you have figured out which one is bottleneck you can try to optimize that side.

glDrawElements can be a minor improvement over glDrawArrays because vertex shader can run once for each vertex that is used multiple times in mesh. But more important GPU side optimizations can fragment shader, avoiding blending, making sure depth test is correctly preventing redrawing same pixel location multiple times etc. Of course if you have complex geometry then vertex processing can be bottleneck too.

Quick estimates how much something costs:

- Call to java code once 0.001-0.01ms (CPU)
- glDraw* once with VBO/IBO 0.01-0.1ms (CPU)
- Cheap vertex shader 0.1-1ms (GPU)
- Expensive vertex shader 1-10ms (GPU)
- Cheap whole screen fragment shader 2-5ms (GPU)
- Expensive fragment shader 30-100ms (GPU)
- Whole screen blending N times will cost N times fragment shader cost (GPU)

DISCLAIMER: Numbers are just very rough estimates. You should use profiling and benchmarks to find real values for your use case.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for you answer. I would accept it as correct answer if you would also mention the EGLConfigs, which can improve GPU performance quite a bit (I got my app from rendering 15fps to 30fps by improving my EGLConfigs. I disabled AA and i set STENCIL_BUFFER from 8 to 1). Unfortunately we can not use glDrawElements over glDrawArray, but i get your point (by using index-data for tris, we could reduce amount of vertex-calculations). Currently we are thinking of ways to prevent redrawing of same pixel-location.